# How to draw text above a UIImage to create a new Image

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage

I'm attempting to create a UIImage using an existing UIImage and a String.

I've been trying to use this code within a playground:

```
import UIKit

let filter = CIFilter(name: "CIQRCodeGenerator")!

var data = "cat".dataUsingEncoding(NSISOLatin1StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: false)

filter.setValue(data, forKey: "inputMessage")
filter.setValue("Q", forKey: "inputCorrectionLevel")

var image = filter.outputImage!

let scaleX = CGFloat(9.8)
let scaleY = CGFloat(9.8)

let img = UIImage(CIImage: image.imageByApplyingTransform(CGAffineTransformMakeScale(scaleX, scaleY)))

var textColor = UIColor.blackColor()

var textFont = UIFont(name: "Helvetica Bold", size: 12)!

let scale = UIScreen.mainScreen().scale

UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSize(width: img.size.width, height: img.size.height), false, scale)

let textFontAttributes = [
    NSFontAttributeName: textFont,
    NSForegroundColorAttributeName: textColor
    ]

img.drawAtPoint(CGPoint(x: 0, y: 100))

var rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, img.size.width, img.size.height)

NSString(string: "cat").drawInRect(rect, withAttributes: textFontAttributes)

var newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()

UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

return newImage
```

Unfortunately while this does overlay text onto the existing image, since it's a QR image I'm overlaying on I would like to leave some space between the top of the QR image and the text.

I feel like this shouldn't be a difficult thing to achieve, although need some guidance.

Thank you

Comment: I don't understand the question. You are the one who is drawing the image with `drawAtPoint` and `drawInRect` (why are you using both???) and the text with `drawInRect`. So you are saying where they go. If you don't like where you're putting them, put them where you do like.

Comment: My bad, I put in code that I had tried to get working.  Updated it.

Answer (score 0):

I realized what I was doing wrong.

The initial space that I created with this line:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSize(width: img.size.width, height: img.size.height), false, scale)
```

was limiting the height of the drawable space.

So I tried to then draw the Image 100 y lower using:

```
img.drawAtPoint(CGPoint(x: 0, y: 100))
```

although it was getting cut off.

So I then realized I needed to make the initial space taller like this:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSize(width: img.size.width, height: img.size.height + 100), false, scale)
```

Thanks!